# Como eu faço para filtar os dados de forma decrescente?

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando filtrar os dados de uma tabela em que tenho no `SQL` do maior valor para o menor, porém não estou conseguindo de jeito algum com MySQL.

Código fonte abaixo

```
select max(id_nf), min(quantidade * valor_unit) AS VALOR_TOTAL from objects,
```

Exercício abaixo:

Pesquise o valor total das `NF` e ordene o resultado do maior valor para o menor. As colunas presentes no resultado da consulta são: `ID_NF`, `VALOR_TOTAL`.

Observação: O `VALOR_TOTAL` é obtido pela fórmula: `∑ QUANTIDADE * VALOR_UNIT`.

Comment: qual problema está encontrando?

Comment: Ele esta imprimindo apenas um valor, quando eu precisa diversos valores viessem a ser imprimidos do maior para o maior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o que o exercicio pede é um sum do valor total que seria :

```
select id_nf,sum(quantidade * valor_unit) as valor_total 
from objects 
group by id_nf 
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Conseguiu me ajudar, obrigado meu consagrado!